# Python: Why is list comprehension slower than for loop

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

Essentially these are the same functions - except list comprehension uses `sum` instead of `x=0; x+=` since the later is not supported. Why is list comprehension compiled to something 40% slower?

```
#list comprehension
def movingAverage(samples, n=3): 
    return [float(sum(samples[i-j] for j in range(n)))/n for i in range(n-1, len(samples))]

#regular
def moving_average(samples, n=3):
    l =[]
    for i in range(n-1, len(samples)):
        x= 0
        for j in range(n): 
            x+= samples[i-j]
        l.append((float(x)/n))
    return l
```

For timing the sample inputs I used variations on `[i*random.random() for i in range(x)]`

Comment: You are making some extra operations in the *list comprehension*, like converting to `float` and dividing by `n`.

Comment: I do have float in both. I just forgot to add it into stackoverflow. It's because I was testing in Python2 which defaults to to int on division.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using a generator expression in your list comprehension:

```
sum(samples[i-j] for j in range(n))
```

Generator expressions require a new frame to be created each time you run one, just like a function call. This is relatively expensive.

You don't need to use a generator expression at all; you only need to *slice* the `samples` list:

```
sum(samples[i - n + 1:i + 1])
```

You can specify a second argument, a `start` value for the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum); set it to `0.0` to get a float result:

```
sum(samples[i - n + 1:i + 1], 0.0)
```

Together these changes make all the difference:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import random
>>> testdata = [i*random.random() for i in range(1000)]
>>> def slow_moving_average(samples, n=3):
...     return [float(sum(samples[i-j] for j in range(n)))/n for i in range(n-1, len(samples))]
... 
>>> def fast_moving_average(samples, n=3):
...     return [sum(samples[i - n + 1:i + 1], 0.0) / n for i in range(n-1, len(samples))]
... 
>>> def verbose_moving_average(samples, n=3):
...     l =[]
...     for i in range(n-1, len(samples)):
...         x = 0.0
...         for j in range(n): 
...             x+= samples[i-j]
...         l.append(x / n)
...     return l
... 
>>> timeit('f(s)', 'from __main__ import verbose_moving_average as f, testdata as s', number=1000)
0.9375386269966839
>>> timeit('f(s)', 'from __main__ import slow_moving_average as f, testdata as s', number=1000)
1.9631599469939829
>>> timeit('f(s)', 'from __main__ import fast_moving_average as f, testdata as s', number=1000)
0.5647804250038462
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you're right about the extra generator frame. sum across a slice is faster than a second for loop.

Comment: Also I wanted to add that it's not obvious that sum across a slice would be faster - for example in Julia the for-loop implementation out performs the slice.