# for loop vs. all() execution speed

Tags: python, for-loop

Hello I think the two snippet below should essentially do the same thing:

```
for divisor in range(2, 21):
    if sample % divisor != 0:
        break
```

The first snippet, I use `sample` divided by number from 2 to 20, if any one of them gives remainder != 0, then I will `break` and try `sample += 1` (codes omitted)

```
if all(sample % divisor == 0 for divisor in range(2, n2+1)):
    return sample
```

The second snippet I will return the sample if `all()` comes back with `True`, otherwise I will try `sample += 1` (codes omitted)

**The second snippet is found twice slower than the first one.** I don't understand, when python evaluate all(), if one `False` was found in iteration, it should immediately comes back `False` for all(), instead of finish the whole iteration, right?

So why is the second snippet slower than the first one?

Comment: Why do you have *two* loops for `divisor` in the second snippet?

Comment: because there's an extra useless loop in the second case.

Comment: Function calls have overhead. Genexps have overhead. And, as others are pointing out, you have an extra loop.

Comment: "The second snippet is found twice slower than the first one" Well that's kind off obvious. You have 2 `for` loops in the second example.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not the point here. ok: "loops have overhead".

Comment: Sorry guys, what a terrible mistake........

Comment: I fixed the codes, that was a typo, but even now it is still much much slower

Comment: Yes, that's expected -- a genexp creates an object for which `next()` is called to get the next item. Function calls have overhead. Others have asked this question before, and it already has answers in the knowledgebase.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You mean that all() will create an generator during the evaluation?

Comment: I mean that `foo for bar in baz` is a genexp literal in that context. (If you put it in square brackets, it would be a list comprehension instead). It's not `all` that's doing it, but the one-line `for` syntax (when not in list-comprehension context).

Comment: ...this is very closely related to, if not outright duplicative of, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905965/python-why-is-list-comprehension-slower-than-for-loop

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ...so, I think it *did* end up being the point.

Comment: you were lucky :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your hint:

```
>>> (sample % divisor == 0 for divisor in range(2, n2+1))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10ead7a00>
```

Your code is creating a genexp, and requiring `all` to call the `next` method on that genexp over and over.

This has an unavoidable performance penalty over a `for` loop involving no function calls. See also [Python: Why is list comprehension slower than for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905965/python-why-is-list-comprehension-slower-than-for-loop)

Comment: This is so helpful! Very clear explanation. I never thought about this level at all.