# mapping is slower than for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda, mapping, list-comprehension

there was similar question
[Python: Why is list comprehension slower than for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905965/python-why-is-list-comprehension-slower-than-for-loop)
but this doesn't explain my problem

I have written a code for multiplying two matrices in one I have used the simple approach

```
def multiply(A, B):
    if A.column_count == B.row_count:
        transpose_of_B = B.transpose().matrix
        data_structure = []
        for row in A.matrix:
            row_column = []
            for column in transpose_of_B:
                row_column_array = list(zip(row, column))
                total = 0
                for element_product in row_column_array:
                    total += element_product[0]*element_product[1]
                row_column.append(total)
            data_structure.append(row_column)
        return Matrix(data_structure)
    else:
        raise Exception(
            "NOT CONFORMABLE!! column_count does not match the row_count")
```

and diff. approach

```
    if A.column_count == B.row_count:
        product_matrix = Matrix([[sum(list(map(lambda x, y:x*y, A.row(r+1), B.column(c+1))))
                                 for c in range(B.column_count)] for r in range(A.row_count)])
    return product_matrix
```

someone please explain why there is a significant diff in runtime

Comment: try to add: a = time.time() in the first of the function and: b = time.time() in the end of the function and the (b - a) will give you the total time (in seconds) the function run

Comment: yes I have done that and the first one is faster than 2nd one I ran the function over 1000 times and the first one was twice times faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing two totally different approaches. In the first, you iterate over rows, in the second you only have a for-loop of the index and access rows via `A.row()`.

This would be a similar list comprehension:

```
    transpose_of_B = B.transpose().matrix
    product_matrix = Matrix([[sum(map(lambda x, y: x*y, row, column))
                             for column in transpose_of_B] for row in A.matrix])
```

Comment: oh okay should I give the complete code for the work if it is difficult to understand and how can I make the second one faster